# Comment parts highlighted (Atom)

Tags: syntax, highlight, atom-editor

Why are some parts of the commented section highlighted? I haven't seen such editor behaviour in others code. It really distracts me.
Can I dim it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

The quickest way is to edit `.atom/styles.less`

```
atom-text-editor::shadow {
  .php {
    .comment {
      .keyword {
        color: inherit;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

More info [here](http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization/#style-tweaks)